# How to configure the new theme of Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office, themes

Recently I upgraded my Windows 10 to version 20H2, and I saw my office suite theme changed from the upper one to the lower one like the figure below.

[image: Two kinds of office themes]

The most noticeable difference is the ribbon bar. The old one has large color blocks while the new one has a line under the active tab.

However, this change only lasted about 3 days, and my office strangely become back to the upper one automatically.

Personally I like the new theme very much, and I'm looking for a way to configure that.

I am using Office 2016.

Comment: Is your Office fully up to date?  All Office here is in the newer format.   Any Office, File, Account, and then use the updater.  I hope that works for you.

Comment: Your Windows upgrade didn’t change your office theme.  Only one of those screenshots are from Office 2016.

Comment: The second ribbon bar is for Microsoft 365 apps. I think there maybe something wrong afther Windows update and it went away after 3 days, then the ribbon bar goes back to normal.

Comment: Thank you, John, Ramhound and Emily for your reply! Yes at the time when the ribbon bar is like the second one, there is also a "Office 365" text caption swiping over the startup screen of Word, Excel, etc. So it seems that @Emily got it right. I don't have an Office 365 subscription so there's probably no way to solve this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have Office 365 installed in addition to Office 2016, and the Windows 10 install may have surfaced the shortcuts for Office 365, and you ended up opening them for that period of time you noticed the different UI.

I would further imagine that if you looked at your computer you'd likely see Office 365 products are still there.

HOWEVER, if you have failed to note that this is a work computer, it's also possible that someone managing your computer may have installed the Office 365 by mistake, and rolled this mistake back, removing the Office 365 components and reinstalling Office 2016.